# Is there a light theme for Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use a light theme on my app, but in a way so that I can customize it (hints why I'm creating my own theme).  Despite using `AppTheme.NoActionBar` I still see a bar while my app is loading at the top.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">

</style>
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

I'm using the latest version of Android, using Nexus_S as my device.

Answer (score 1):

What device are your using?
If you are using emulator, what is the level of the API?

If the API is lower than 3 Android does not support the actionbar. Only if the API is equal to 3 or higher the NoActionBar theme will apply.

In my experience when porting in Nexus one API 2.3, Even when I want to show the actionbar, There is just a thin bar on top of the screen.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Theme.Sherlock.Light.

If you are using Sherlock actionbar you can use this.